# Firebase Firestore Android - Empty List

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to android, but I have a problem now. My list is empty and I don't understand why ... I want to access that data from another collection.

First I retrieve the ID of the first collection and use that ID to access the next one and thus retrieve the data from the last collection. Can someone help me please?

```
private void loadList() {
//        list.clear();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        documentReference.collection("vendas").get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            for (DocumentSnapshot doc : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                String id = doc.getId();
                documentReference.collection("vendas").document(id).collection("parcelas").orderBy("parcela").get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
                            for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : Objects.requireNonNull(task1.getResult())) {
                                Parcela value = Objects.requireNonNull(documentSnapshot.toObject(Parcela.class));
                                if (value.getStatus().contains("AB")) {
                                    list.add(value);
                                    Log.d(TAG, value.getValor() + " - venc: " + value.getVencimento());
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                layoutEmpity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                layoutEmpity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            Log.d(TAG, Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        });
    }
```

Comment: When you query the first time, do you get the results from that query?

Comment: Yes, from the first query yes and from the second within the first loop I get it too, it appears in my cat log, but the list is still empty.

Comment: How do you check if the list is empty?

Comment: When running the application on my phone.
Or through "list.size ()"